# geometry nodes disappear after applying

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I made a geo nodes setup for the ball and used a object info of a single ball but when i apply the geometry nodes in the modifiers tab every ball disappears from the scene except the original ball. Help Please...
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add a realize instances node before your group output.

[image]